# How to auto-format and auto-capitalize SQL in Vim

Tags: sql, features, vim

I'd like to use vim to write SQL queries, but haven't figured out how to get two key features that I use all the time in programs like SQL Yog.

I usually start an instance of Yog in the background, cut-and-paste my SQL into it, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> which auto-formats the whole thing. All the SQL keywords are automatically capitalized as soon as the text is pasted. I then copy it back into whatever other tool I'm using (often SQL Query Browser at work) and go from there.  The benefits of these two features are worth the extra effort.

Does anyone know how I can set up vim to do this? I still may need to cut and paste back into Query Browser, which is acceptable to me, but I'd like to stick with vim for all my editing.

Comment: The [SQLUtilities](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=492) vim script can format SQL quite nicely for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put some `autocmd`s for SQL files in your `.vimrc` that execute a bunch of `:ab` commands to auto-replace common keywords with their capitalized variants.

Going further, you could also write your own indentation script and attach it to `indentexpr`.

If you need to do this inline in another file type (i.e., you're writing SQL queries in strings in, say, PHP), you'll probably have to do this in a scratch buffer anyway, or modify your language's ftplugin to use your `indentexpr` in an "SQL mode."

Comment: To be honest, I don't see the need for capitalization. A judiciously formatted multi-line string with syntax highlighting has always been sufficient for me.

Comment: I agree on capitalization. I prefer all lowercase for SQL, and I think the convention to use all caps is rather horrible. Lowercase is much more readable, and easier to type.

Answer (score 2):

I just put this map in my .vimrc:

```
" prettify sql:
vnoremap <Leader>rp :s/\<update\>\\|\<select\>\\|\<from\>\\|\<where>\\|\<left join\>\\|\<inner join\>\\|\<group by\>\\|\<order by\>/\r\U&/ge<cr><esc>
```

I've mapped it rp - but choose what you want. (rp = run prettify)

The way to use it is visually select your query (eg*emphasized text* with

```
vip
```

or whatever, then press J to join your query into one line, then run this map.